# Installing Freya on Surface Pro 2

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, surface-tablet

Today I tried to install elementary OS Freya 0.3.2. When I installed it, all elements of interface were too big, but I installed it with <kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. After rebooting, the type cover keyboard and Wi-Fi didn't work. Can I fix these problems or should wait for the Loki release based on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Don't expect a M$ computer to run Linux.They do not run them without a lot of tweaking (recompiling the kernel)

Comment: I used Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 and everything was OK, without compiling